# Nginx Regex and optional backreference

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre, backreference

I want to optionally match a string (asdf) and remove it from a rewrite.

```
location ~ /somefolder {
    rewrite ^/somefolder(.*)(?:asdf)?(.*html)$ http://example.com$1$2 permanent;
}
```

So this would rewrite the requested url to the root domain as well as strip the url of any occurrence of `asdf` if present.

Below the address `mydomain.com/somefolder/pencil.html` is rewritten to `mydomain.com/pencil.html`

```
2013/09/16 09:52:24 [notice] 16866#0: *1 "^/somefolder(.*)(?:asdf)?(.*html)$" matches "/somefolder/pencil.html", client: 10.0.0.2, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /somefolder/pencil.html HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com"
2013/09/16 09:52:24 [notice] 16866#0: *1 rewritten redirect: "http://mydomain.com/pencil.html", client: 10.0.0.2, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /somefolder/pencil.html HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com"
```

Where as here `mydomain.com/somefolder/pencil-asdf.html` is rewritten to `mydomain.com/pencil-asdf.html`

```
2013/09/16 09:52:31 [notice] 16866#0: *1 "^/somefolder(.*)(?:asdf)?(.*html)$" matches "/somefolder/pencil-asdf.html", client: 10.0.0.2, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /somefolder/pencil-asdf.html HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com"
2013/09/16 09:52:31 [notice] 16866#0: *1 rewritten redirect: "http://mydomain.com/pencil-asdf.html", client: 10.0.0.2, server: mydomain.com, request: "GET /somefolder/pencil-asdf.html HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.com"
```

Shouldn't `asdf` be getting stripped using the `(?:asdf)` match yielding `mydomain.com/pencil-.html`

Comment: You should add an answer to your question and accept it - will make it easier for people to work out that there is a solution, if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution so that I just use the back refs $1 and $3 ignoring $2 whether it is matched or null.

```
rewrite ^/somefolder(.*)(asdf)(.*html)$ http://example.com$1$3 permanent;
```